# Get sum of array of objects mongodb spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents of collection "consumption" which are composed of:

```
{
    _id:1,
    meterId:1,
    Date: 2021-03-01,
    consumption:[
        { value:10},
        {value:7}
    ]
}
```

i want to return a list of documents filtered by a list of meterId, in addition to the sum of their consumption.
the document i want to return a list of:

```
{
    meterId:1,
    Date: 2021-03-01
    consumption:[
        { value:10},
        {value:7}
    ],
    total:17
}
```

I've seen questions answering how to do this, but none really showed how to map the lists' fields to another object for all the objects retrieved.

I created a consumptionDTO to have the same fields of consumption, in addition to a total field.

```
public class ConsumptionDTO {

    protected Date date;

    protected String meterId;

    protected List<ConsumptionPoint> consumption;

    protected double total; //the added field
//constructor, getters and setters
}
```

I've tried this:

```
    List<ConsumptionDTO> consumptions =new ArrayList<>();

    AggregationOperation filter =    Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("meterId").in(meterIds).and("date").gte(startDate).lte(endDate));

    AggregationOperation sum = Aggregation.group().sum("consumption.value").as("total");

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(filter, sum);

    consumptions = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,collectionName,ConsumptionDTO.class).getMappedResults();
```

but the returned consumptions is always empty. any idea on how to fix this? I'm still new to spring and mongodb, so I apologize if it's already answered elsewhere and I didn't get it.

Comment: With mongo aggregation you can do it as follow without grouping in case you need per object , but you can group also if you need for all objects: https://mongoplayground.net/p/58NWv9pQPrR

Comment: @R2D2 how can I do that in spring? I can't seem to use sum without grouping